# Программирование с учётом АЛУ на асме и макс нагрузке?

Tags: ассемблер, производительность, железо, intel

В последнее время всё чаще посещает мысль написать ультрапроизводительное приложение, обычно пишу программки далёкие от производительности. и тут на днях прочёл статью на хакере
 https://xakep.ru/2013/02/19/60145/
всё решил пишу! ни каких безопастностей! ни каких мультиплатформенностей! ни каких модульностей! ни каких юзверей!
только я! только нужное! только моя хардварь! остальное лишнее!

А если конкретней, то где прочесть нечто подобное, а так же про планировщик АЛУ, и мою архитектуру проца (сколько алушек и размеры всяких кэшей команд)?, ещё интересует Hyper-threading в частности
если использовать одни и те же команды на 2 виртуальных ядрах одного физического, будет ли ускорение?

Мой ноут: msi gt72 2qd dominator проц: intel i7-5700HQ(4:8 ядер 2.7GHz 6mb-L3).  Пока видюху и сопутствующие вычисления не затрагиваем.
Знаю более менее асм, а f,t,m - не важно, схема мне и так понятна

Comment: На сайте intel поищите, там можно нарыть подходящие datasheet'ы. Хотя возможно часть из них доступна только по запросу

Comment: А еще, особенно учитывая что у вас ноут а у них процессор может использоваться для процедур управления питанием вам надо где то раздобыть даташит конкретно на вашу мать/ревизию bios и понять используется ли режим SMM и если да то какие ядра могут в него переводится аппаратурой

Comment: Если говорить про производительность любой ценой, то в порядке убывания скорости, повышения гибкости/лёгкости разработки: ASIC, FPGA, GPU, CPU (если задача позволяет, то даже скромненькая видео-карта может многократно превосходить мощный CPU). [On Fair Comparison between CPU and GPU](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sangjin/2013/02/12/CPU-GPU-comparison.html)

Comment: @jfs я в курсе преимуществ видеокарт, но процессор же тоже нужен и в такие моменты хочется использовать его по максимуму и ещё видеокарта может быть занята графикой

Comment: Hyper-threading помогает только от неправильного предсказания ветвления, собственно это было придумано как костыль для Pentium 4